# Sharing wireless internet connection between 2 Ubuntu 10.04 systems using cross-over cable

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Lenovo T60 with Ubuntu 10.04 connected with a cross-over cable to a Dell Vostro 1400, also running Ubuntu 10.04.  My internet is coming into the Lenovo through an external wireless antennae, and I want to share the internet with the Dell.

On the Lenovo:
  eth0 connection has IPv4 Settings 'Shared to other computers'
  I can ping the Dell (10.42.43.10) successfully
  I can use mtr to trace to www.google.com successfully

On the Dell:
  eth0 connection has IPv4 Settings 'Automatic DHCP'
  I can ping the Lenovo (10.42.43.1) successfully
  when I use mtr to trace to www.google.com, I can only reach 10.42.43.1

I must be missing some setting, but cannot see what it is; can anyone help me?

Comment: just to note, most modern systems, should probably autonegotiate networking, so so using a crossover cable isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well another very simple setting could be using a static IP address scheme on both machines, so for instance

Dell 10.42.43.10
Lenovo 10.42.43.11

with the same subnet mask lets say 255.255.255.0 or /24.

Once this is done you can easily through the network manager share the Wifi connection through the cable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive description how to do this in the Ubuntu help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

In particular, the package `dnsmasq-base` must be installed.

Try installing the package, then reboot, and do the setup again, then try again with a client computer.

If it still fails, have a look at the system logs (`/var/log/syslog`), there might be a helpful message there.

To troubleshoot, get a root shell on the client computer (`sudo su`), then type:

```
dhclient -d
```

This will try to obtain network parameters automatically (via DHCP). If it fails, something is wrong on the ICS server. If it works, you're good.